# Is it possible to set multiple items selected in QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

`setCurrentItem` only sets one item selected. I don't see any method to set more than 1 item selected programmatically, but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Of course, my tree widget is configured to enable multiple selection.

Note that I'm using `QTreeWidget`, not `QTreeView`.

Comment: setCurrentItem is responsible for cursor, not for selection

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Thank you very much! I was confusing the two. Your remarks helps me to fix another problem I've been having :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setSelectionMode`:

```
treeWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

And on the items you can use `setSelected`:

```
treeWidgetItem->setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use the selection model:

```
QModelIndex index = ...; // index you want to select.
QItemSelectionModel* sel_model = tree_view->selectionModel();
sel_model->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

There are other ways of manipulating the selection mode - see the Qt Assistant for more details.